# Given a function, find the sum of the parameters of the function such that the function is continuous.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Consider following function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      px & x \in [0,1) \\
      m & x = 1 \\
      x^3 + q & x \in (1, 2] 
   \end{cases}
$$

and also the following set:

$$A = \{ (p, m, q) \in \mathbb{R^3 | \hspace{0.1cm} \text{f differentiable on} \hspace{0.1cm}(0,2)} \}$$

and the sum

$$S = \sum_{(p,m,q) \in A} (p+m+q)$$

I have to find the value of $S$.

This is what I tried.

I know that if the function is differentiable, then it is continuous. The above function is continous only if the following relation is true:

$$p=m=1+q$$

But if I rewrite $2$ of the parameters in terms of the other one I get the following:

$$\sum_{(p,m,q)\in A}(p+m+q) = \sum_{(p, m , q) \in A} (p + p + p -1) = \sum_{(p,m,q) \in A}(3p - 1)$$

And I got stuck. I don't even know if what I did so far is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done so far looks correct. Next, since $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(0,2)$, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}f'(x) & = \lim_{x\to 1^{+}}f'(x) \\
\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}p & = \lim_{x\to 1^{+}}3x^2 \\
p & = 3
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is due to, as Wikipedia's [Differentiable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) article says,

> As a result, the [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) of a differentiable function must have a (non-[vertical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_tangent)) [tangent line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_line) at each interior point in its domain, be relatively smooth, and cannot contain any break, angle, or [cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)).

I'll leave it to you to finish the rest.

Comment: Am I right to say that there is only one tuple $(p, m, q)$ that satisfy the conditions, namely $ (3,3,2)$, so the sum is $8$?

Comment: @user1502 Yes, there's only the one set of values you state which satisfy the question conditions, so the sum would be $8$.